# How can I handle multiple uncooperative API classes and make them cooperative?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

Inspired by @Raymond Hettinger's *"Super considered super"* [blogpost](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) and [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) I have become a huge fan of cooperative multiple inheritance in Python.

However, not everyone is aware of this feature in python and often one has to use code which cannot be modified *(3rd party, etc)*. This brings many uncooperative players to the game, that is classes which do not call `super` nicely.

One uncooperative base class can be managed by putting it at the end of the `MRO`:

```
class External1(object):
    """Nobody touch this code!"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.important = "super"
class MyClass(MyCooperativeClass,External1):
    pass
```

How can I extend this pattern to multiple classes and e.g. make sure all `__init__(*args,**kwargs)` are called?

```
class External2(object):
    """Nobody is touching this file!"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.main_functionality = 5  # Chosen by dice roll, guaranteed to be random

class MyChild(MycooperativeClass, External1, External2):
    pass
```

Is there a way to add cooperativeness onto a non-cooperative class?

Comment: Use a decorator around your "uncooperative" classes (add a metaclass).

Answer (score 0):

From the blog post you linked, he describes using an adapter to achieve results. For your example, you could do something like this:

```
class Root(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self)

class Extarnal1Adapter(Root):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.external1 = External1(*args, **kwargs)
        self.important = self.external1.important
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Extarnal2Adapter(Root):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.external2 = External2(*args, **kwargs)
        self.main_functionality = self.external2.main_functionality
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MyChild(MycooperativeClass, External1Adapter, External2Adapter):
    pass
```